# can't install the newest version gganimate package as if dependency 'transformr' is not available

Tags: r, gganimate

I am using the newest software versions:

R 3.5.1, R Studio 1.1.456, Rtools 3.5

And I am getting the following error message:

```
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o transformr.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o align_rings.o sf_packing.o triangulate.o -LD:/R/R-35~1.1/bin/x64 -lR
installing to D:/R/R-3.5.1/library/transformr/libs/x64
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Warning: S3 methods '$.bbox', '$.crs', '$<-.sf', '[.sf', '[.sfc', '[<-.sfc', '[[<-.sf', 'st_agr<-.sf', 'st_crs<-.sf', 'st_crs<-.sfc', 'st_geometry<-.data.frame', 'st_geometry<-.sf', 'Ops.crs', 'Ops.sfc', 'Ops.sfg', 'Ops.sgbp', 'aggregate.sf', 'as.data.frame.sf', 'as.data.frame.sfc', 'as.data.frame.sgbp', 'as.matrix.sfg', 'as.matrix.sgbp', 'c.sfc', 'c.sfg', 'cbind.sf', 'dim.sgbp', 'format.sfc', 'format.sfg', 'head.sfg', 'identify.sf', 'identify.sfc', 'is.na.bbox', 'is.na.crs', 'merge.sf', 'plot.sf', 'plot.sfc_CIRCULARSTRING', 'plot.sfc_GEOMETRY', 'plot.sfc_GEOMETRYCOLLECTION', 'plot.sfc_LINESTRING', 'plot.sfc_MULTILINESTRING', 'plot.sfc_MULTIPOINT', 'plot.sfc_MULTIPOLYGON', 'plot.sfc_POINT', 'plot.sfc_POLYGON', 'plot.sfg', 'print.bbox', 'print.crs', 'print.sf', 'print.sf_layers', 'print.sfc', 'print.sfg', 'print.sgbp', 'rbind.sf', 'rep.sfc', 'st_agr.character', 'st_agr.default', 'st_agr.factor', 'st_agr.sf', 'st_as_binary.sfc', 'st_as_binary.sfg', 'st_as_grob.CIRCULARSTRING', 'st_as_grob.COMPOUN [... truncated]
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  DLL 'sf' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'transformr'
* removing 'D:/R/R-3.5.1/library/transformr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
"D:/R/R-35~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore  \
  --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Temp/RtmpeE3VDN/devtools22dc79ce1d1/thomasp85-gganimate-ef2e717"  \
  --library="D:/R/R-3.5.1/library" --install-tests 

ERROR: dependency 'transformr' is not available for package 'gganimate'
* removing 'D:/R/R-3.5.1/library/gganimate'
In R CMD INSTALL
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

Can you give me a solution?

Comment: Try installing [transformr's imports](https://github.com/thomasp85/transformr/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) as binaries first.

Comment: when I install tranformR package, the error message appear as following:Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  DLL 'sf' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'transformr'
* removing 'D:/R/R-3.5.1/library/transformr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Installation failed: Command failed (1)

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested, i.e., install the packages transformr imports as binaries?

Comment: Could you tell me the step how to install the package transformr imports as bin?I just install the package transformR, it begin appear the error message as :DLL 'sf' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture? I can't install transfromR package.how to deal with it? Thx!

Comment: You are not reading my comments carefully. Please reread and try to understand what I'm actually saying.

Comment: Thx for Roland's suggested.because my English is poor.I can't understand his comments. and according to his suggestion, I check transformR's imports packcage. according to the error message as :"DLL 'sf' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture? " I check the sf package at frist. it can't open. so I confrimed the really issue is here.I deleted the package and reinstall it sucessfully, and then reinstall transformR sucessfully.  and then reinstall gganimate package sucessfully. all problem had been sloved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for Roland's suggested.because my English is poor.I can't understand his comments. and according to his suggestion, I check transformR's imports packcage. according to the error message as :"DLL 'sf' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture? " I check the sf package at frist. it can't open. so I confrimed the really issue is here.I deleted the package and reinstall it sucessfully, and then reinstall transformR sucessfully.  and then reinstall gganimate package sucessfully. all problem had been sloved. and now I still not understand the word "as binaries" what mean it is.although it is not important. Thx Roland again.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, I reinstalled tranformR, Rtools and added **C:\Rtools\bin**, **C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin** to the environment paths.  Restarted R and it was working.  (note:- make sure Rtools is installed in C:)

Comment: try reinstalling devtools once , i tried doing that and it worked